# Rego - Combine Values of Case Sensitive Keys from json like abc, ABc to single lowercase key abc

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent, rego

I've below json as an input:

```
{
    "data": {
        "abc": 123,
        "Abc": 345,
        "bcd": 789
    }
}
```

I want the result like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "abc": "123,345",
        "bcd": "789"
    }
}
```

i.e. case insensitive key and the values as list or comma-separated String.

For below code block, it's giving error like

> policy.rego:3: eval_conflict_error: object keys must be unique

```
result := {lower(key): input.data[key] | count(key)>0}
```

[Here's](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/EGuFq5IVfD) a rego playground link.

I'm really newbie to rego and not able to understand if this can be done. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely doable in Rego, but it does require getting comfortable with [array comprehensions](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#comprehensions) first!

```
package stackoverflow.example

result[k] := v {
    # Find a value `i`, and assign `k` to be that value lowercased.
    some i
    input.data[i]
    k := lower(i)

    # We use an array comprehension to generate a list.
    # A separate "some" variable is needed here for the comprehension,
    # because `i` has already been assigned a fixed value.
    some j
    values := [format_int(x, 10) | x := input.data[j]; lower(j) == k]
    v := concat(",", values)
}
```

Interactive Rego Playground [link](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/JYDo94nW2F)

You can code-golf this down a bit as well, although it's a bit more cluttered:

```
golfed_version[k] := v {
    some i, j
    input.data[i]
    k := lower(i)
    v := concat(",", [format_int(x, 10) | x := input.data[j]; lower(j) == k])
}
```